# How to list all the functions in an Azure Function App

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I can use the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-AzureRMResource` to list all Azure resources.

Is there a cmdlet that takes a `ResourceGroupName` and a `SiteName` and it returns all the functions in that "Site".

Or, a combination of cmdlets that I can use to get these details.

Comment: Did you try something like(not tested) `Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/functions`

Comment: Yeah, no results returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Fabio Cavalcante said, Azure PowerShell does not support this, you could use Rest API to get it. Here is a example how to get Functions with PowerShell.

#

```
#get token
$TENANTID="<tenantid>"
$APPID="<application id>"
$PASSWORD="<app password>"
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
$token=$result.access_token

##set Header
$Headers=@{
    'authorization'="Bearer $token"
    'host'="management.azure.com"
}

$functions = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptions id>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function name>/functions?api-version=2015-08-01"  -Headers $Headers -ContentType "application/json" -Method GET

$functions.value
```

[image]

Comment: I will give this a try. The link Fabio gave, I couldn't get to work, and was going to try to use them with the `scm` endpoint.

Is it possible this "workflow" will be encapsulated as PS function going forward?

Comment: Doug, can you clarify what didn't work for you with the link provided?

Comment: I tried the "uri" in the link you provided with Invoke-RestMethod with the proper substitutions. I tried Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId. I also tried Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction, parsing out the the uri to the parameters.

Comment: @DougFinke Hi, do you get the token?

Comment: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptions id>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function name>/functions?api-version=2015-08-01` Don't use `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction`.  `Invoke-RestMethod` equals `curl`.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Sorry, I update my answer and replace the variables that you have.

Comment: @DougFinke Azure PowerShell could not list detailed function, you should use [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/). For Azure Rest API, you should use service principle to get the token. You also need structure `Header` message like my answer and `request URI` that Azure Function provides.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I know where to find the tenant id. For the APPID and PWD, is that a service principal I need to create?

Comment: Yes, this is service principal. You could create a new one.

Comment: @DougFinke You had better know what is [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/) and how to use it firstly, it is easy.

Comment: Thanks @Walter-MSFT, yeah, I wrapped the KeyVault REST API, at first glance it looks similar.

Answer (score 6):

### In 2021, you can use [`func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=linux%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

```
func azure functionapp list-functions FUNCTION_NAME
```

available in [`azure-functions-core-tools@3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=linux%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

Answer (score 4):

Not a PowerShell cmdlet, but you can use the ListingFunctions API as described [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Functions-API#listing-functions)

```
Listing functions
get /subscriptions/{sub}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionapp}/functions?api-version=2015-08-01

Response:
{
  "value": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using the `Get-AzureRmResource` cmdlet.

```
$Params = @{
    ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroupName
    ResourceType      = 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions'
    ResourceName      = $AppName
    ApiVersion        = '2015-08-01'
}
Get-AzureRmResource @Params
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below

**Disable**

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name <FUNCTION_APP_NAME> -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.<Function_Name>.Disabled" = "true"}
```

**Enable**

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name <FUNCTION_APP_NAME> -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.QueueTrigger.Disabled" = "false"}
```

Comment: Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=powershell

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell to get all the Functions in all ResourceGroup. If only certain RG needed, this can be filtered by uncomment the code where RG filter is.

In my case, I'm looking for Azure Function v3, so I print out only the function V3, but you can filter the list or update the Functions however you want.

```
$subscriptionId = "some-guid-subscription"
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$apps = Get-AzFunctionApp -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
Write-Output ("Checking subscription " + $subscriptionId)
foreach ($app in $apps) {
    # Filter RG here if needed
    #if ($app.ResourceGroupName -ne "a-resource-group") { continue }
    $appsetting = Get-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name $app.Name -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroupName
    if ($appsetting.FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION -eq "~3") {
        Write-Output ($app.Name + " in RG: " + $app.ResourceGroupName + " has version" + $appsetting.FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION)
    }
}
```