# Check if an Azure Function is enabled with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109365/how-to-list-all-the-functions-in-an-azure-function-app), I can get the list of all deployed functions (enabled or not) with the following script, but is there a way to know which ones are disabled?

```
$Params = @{
    ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroupName
    ResourceType      = 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions'
    ResourceName      = $AppName
    ApiVersion        = '2015-08-01'
}
Get-AzureRmResource @Params
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Functions v2, functions are disabled when there's an environment variable present with name `AzureWebJobs.{functionName}.Disabled` and value `true` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function#functions-2x---all-languages).

You can get the function app's environment variables in Azure Powershell with

```
(Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName {resourceGroupName} -Name {appName}).SiteConfig.AppSettings
```

and then filter accordingly.