# Get list of actual Azure Function endpoints from Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-management-api

I'm trying to get a full list of function endpoints in my Azure function app from a Powershell script.  I can get the list of functions from the management.azure.com API, but it just has the function name, like...

```
/subscriptions/ea4a3766-c3a8-4b9c-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MyFunctionAppName/functions/FunctionName
```

But the function actually has an endpoint of (for instance) `http://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/allsources/{sourceName}`

How can I get that endpoint name from the Azure management API from Powershell?  It's displayed in the "Get Function URL" button on the portal, so I would imagine it has to be there somewhere.

EDIT: The suggested duplicate still doesn't provide the actual function endpoint.  For instance, I have a function called CheckLock. Its endpoint per the "Get Function URL" button on the portal (and the one that I want) is: `https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/account/lock/{id}?code=myfunctioncode`

What I'm getting from the suggested duplicate is:

```
@{
name=CheckLock; 
function_app_id=/subscriptions/ea4a3766-c3a8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myfunctionappname;
script_root_path_href=https://myfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/CheckLock/; 
script_href=https://myfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/bin/Funcs.dll; 
config_href=https://myfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/CheckLock/function.json; 
secrets_file_href=https://myfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/functions/secrets/CheckLock.json; 
href=https://myfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/CheckLock;
config=; 
files=; 
test_data=
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all the functions in an Azure Function App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109365/how-to-list-all-the-functions-in-an-azure-function-app)

Comment: Not exactly...that's not getting the actual endpoint, it's getting the scm configuration endpoint, I think.  I'll update the post with info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  In the data for the function itself, the route is part of the properties.config object.

Request should look like this: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionAppName}/functions/{functionName}?api-version=2016-08-01`

In the return value is a `properties` object, and within that is `config` object.  Underneath that is the `route` property which contains the trigger endpoint.

In Powershell, it's this:

```
$functionData = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $functionName -Headers $accessTokenHeader
$triggerUrl = "https://$functionAppName.azurewebsites.net/api/" + $functionData.properties.config.route
```

You can test it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getfunction

Hope this helps someone else!  Thanks to those who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

AZ PowerShell has introduced the [`Invoke-AzResourceAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/invoke-azresourceaction?view=azps-4.3.0) cmdlet. This does exactly what it says on the tin - it allows you to invoke an action against an Azure Resource.

It's possible to get a Function Key and URL through the `listkeys` action as follows -

```
$functionApp = Get-AzWebAppSlot -Name $FunctionAppName -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -Slot $Slot
$functionSecrets = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId ("{0}/functions/{1}" -f $functionApp.Id, $FunctionName) -Action "listkeys" -ApiVersion "2019-08-01" -Force
```

The variable `$functionSecrets` now contains two properties -

- `key`: The default function-level key (will only work for `$FunctionName`).
- `trigger_url`: The URL to trigger `$FunctionName`. Note that this property does not honour custom routes.

Answer (score 0):

The url you can get via `Get Function URL` named `trigger_url`, seems you could not be able to get all of them in a function app, but you can get it for one specific function, See : [Web Apps - List Function Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctionsecrets#code-try-0), the `trigger_url` in the response body is what you want.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}/listsecrets?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Response body:

```
 {
   "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "trigger_url": "https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
```

**Note**: If you get an error like below, you need to add an application setting `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType : Files` for your function app.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Conflict",
    "message": "System.InvalidOperationException: Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration. Please change Environment variable AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType value to 'Files'. For more info, visit https://aka.ms/funcsecrets\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetKeyObjectFromFile>d__9`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Functions\\FunctionManager.cs:line 141\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetFunctionSecretsAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Functions\\FunctionManager.cs:line 220\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Functions.FunctionController.<GetSecrets>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Functions\\FunctionController.cs:line 141"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  The trigger_url value I'm getting back is: `https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/CheckLock?code=xxx`, but the value I'd expect is `https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/account/lock/{id}`.  This is shown in the function.json as 'route'.  Maybe there's a way to just read the content of function.json?

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip : if you can get azure context with Get-AzContext, you can get the access token to the header like this : `(Get-AzContext).TokenCache[0].ReadItems().AccessToken`